# Getting distinct to work

Tags: sql

i am using this

```
SELECT TOP (100) PERCENT 
       CONVERT(char(10), [Reg Date1], 103) AS [Reg Date], 
       Regs
FROM   (SELECT CAST(SetupDateTime AS datetime) AS [Reg Date1], 
               COUNT(DISTINCT ID) AS Regs
        FROM  dbo.tbl_User
        WHERE (CAST(SetupDateTime AS datetime) BETWEEN 
                   CAST(DATEADD(dd, - 7, GETDATE()) AS datetime) AND 
                   CAST(DATEADD(dd, - 1, GETDATE()) AS datetime))
        GROUP BY CAST(SetupDateTime AS datetime)) AS a
ORDER BY [Reg Date1]
```

which then produces

```
Reg Date    Regs
07/12/2011  1
07/12/2011  1
07/12/2011  1
08/12/2011  1
08/12/2011  1
09/12/2011  1
09/12/2011  1
10/12/2011  1
10/12/2011  1
10/12/2011  1
```

but i want it to do

```
Reg Date    Regs
07/12/2011  10
08/12/2011  12
09/12/2011  15
10/12/2011  11
11/12/2011  10
12/12/2011  17
```

i cant seem to get it to group in this way

Comment: Why should the value for Regs on the `07/12/2011` be `10`? Your sample data only shows three times the value `1` which would make a sum of 3, not 10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT     TOP (100) PERCENT CONVERT(char(10), [Reg Date1], 103) AS [Reg Date], Sum(Regs)
FROM         (SELECT     CAST(SetupDateTime AS datetime) AS [Reg Date1], COUNT(DISTINCT ID) AS Regs
                       FROM          dbo.tbl_User
                       WHERE      (CAST(SetupDateTime AS datetime) BETWEEN CAST(DATEADD(dd, - 7, CAST(convert(varchar, GETDATE(), 112) AS datetime)) AS datetime) AND CAST(convert(varchar, GETDATE(), 112) 
                                              AS datetime))
      GROUP BY CAST(SetupDateTime AS datetime)) AS a
group by CONVERT(char(10), [Reg Date1], 103)
ORDER BY CONVERT(char(10), [Reg Date1], 103)
```

Comment: got this error Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Column 'a.Reg Date1' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: @ChrisManko I've editted my answer in a moment, please try again

Comment: got htis error now Msg 8127, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Column "a.Reg Date1" is invalid in the ORDER BY clause because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
im using sql server 2005 if this helps?

Comment: thats working but its getting yesterdays registrations up to the same time today that i ran the query and not for all of yesterday

Comment: yes tried that didnt work, basically the query is getting 24 hours from time of it being executed where as i jsut want it to do all of yesterday

Comment: @ChrisManko: Have you tried changing `CAST(SetupDateTime AS datetime)` to `CAST(SetupDateTime AS date)` throughout your query?

Comment: i get this now Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 4
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AS'.  on this line                         WHERE      (CAST(SetupDateTime AS datetime) BETWEEN CAST(DATEADD(dd, - 7, CAST(convert(varchar, GETDATE(), 112) AS datetime) AS datetime) AND CAST(convert(varchar, GETDATE(), 112)

Comment: this line BETWEEN CAST(DATEADD(dd, - 7, CAST(convert(varchar, GETDATE(), 112) AS datetime) AS datetime)

Comment: @ChrisManko there was a `)` in the wrong place, what about now?

Comment: sorry no that didnt work its jsut moved the dates and is showing todays results

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`SELECT TOP (100) PERCENT CONVERT(char(10), [Reg Date1], 103) AS [Reg Date], COUNT(Regs)`

Note the use of `COUNT` which is I suspect what you are trying to do.

Comment: This will only count the ocurrencies, not the sum of the regs. It may work if all rows returned have only 1 in the regs column.

Comment: The OP is not clear on which aggregation he was trying to achieve as noted in the comments to the original question.